# jQuery .animate function not responding properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, web

So I just posted a question a few minutes ago about my jQuery code not working because of an error and that got answered. However, now, everything looks fine it just does not work or do anything when I ".click" "#equals". Here is my relevant code.

HTML

```
<div id="goDown">
    <img src="waterTankWaterREAL.png" id="water">
</div>
<input type="submit" name="equals" value="Solve" id="equals">
```

CSS

```
#water {
    position: relative;
    left: -4px;   
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0;
    width: 200px;
}
```

"#goDown" does not have any css

JavaScript/jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#equals").click(function() {

        $('#water').animate({'margin-top': '-200px', 'opacity': .65}, 2000);

    });
});
```

Also, do note that I have put an "alert()" inside my $("#equals") function to make sure it works and it does.

Answer (score 1):

I'll update my answer if you update your question, but as it stands you have no element with the id "equals" so you're setting up a click handler on nothing.

I added a button with the ID of "equals" to this demo and things seem to work fine.

```
<button id="equals">click me</button>
```

http://codepen.io/Chevex/pen/VLWxKq